# Center nested divs in bootstrap grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I want to create a layout .I am using bootstrap grid. Here is the example
[image]

How can i center the white div and respectively  div1 and div2 inside white div.

```
     <div class="row">



    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-10" style="background-color:#F1F3F7; min-height:650px;border: 2px solid black ">

    <div class="  col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8" style="background-color:#ffffff;  min-height:500px;border: 2px solid black ">
Need to be centered
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-10" style="background-color:#F1F3F7; margin: 10px; min-height:500px;border: 2px solid black ">

div1

        </div></div>
        <div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-10" style="background-color:#F1F3F7; margin: 10px; min-height:500px;border: 2px solid black ">
div2</div></div>
</div>
</div>





  </div>
```

Comment: Is the outermost area the `<body>` or another `<div>`?

Comment: if you are using bootstrap grid e.g. col-md, col-lg etc. the classes has css property `float: left;` by default. You center align a div, you have to change it to `float:left;` and set margin to `margin: 0 auto;`. Or check the offset classes provided in bootstrap e.g. col-md-offset-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bootstraps `offset`:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"></div>
</div>
```

Change the values accordingly. Or, you can use `margin: 0 auto;`

```
.div-centered{
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Bootstrap 3 has a build in class called `center-block` you could use. Im pretty sure you have to miss the `row` class and use `container`, i may be wrong. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `col-*-offset-*` to push an element to the right.

Be sure that the value of `col-*-*`, the `offset` and the remaining space should still be equals to **12 columns** so that you can center the element

```css
.outermost {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
}

.div1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid pink;
}
.div2 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="outermost container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="div1 col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
      <div class="div2 col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```